# Wizard with JavaFX Accordions

Tags: javafx, accordion

I'm writing a small configuration-wizard-style JavaFX application. I want to force the user through different steps of configuration panes. So I've chosen an accordion container with a few panels. The user is only allowed to proceed to the NEXT or PREVIOUS accordion panel, but may not jump from panel 1 to 3.

I achived this by adding the "Previous" and "Next" button under the accordion and I set the mouse transparency of the accordion to true. Everything works fine so far. The user can walk from panel 1 to 5 and back...

Unfortunately (for any strange reason) the user cannot configure nothing inside the different panels. Wait... I set the mouse transparency to "true", right... But when I set it to false, the user can jump through the panels without any order.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `disable` on each `TitledPane` to `true` until they are allowed to navigate there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way is to set the `collapsible` property of all the panes to `false`, and to set each one to true just when it needs to be expanded or collapsed (which you can do programmatically). This is a little ugly, but here's an example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Accordion;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AccordionBasedWizard extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Accordion accordion = new Accordion();

        for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
            TitledPane pane = new TitledPane("Page "+(i+1), new Label("Wizard page "+(i+1)));
            accordion.getPanes().add(pane);
            pane.setCollapsible(false);
        }


        accordion.setExpandedPane(accordion.getPanes().get(0));

        Button previousButton = new Button("Previous");
        previousButton.disableProperty().bind(accordion.expandedPaneProperty().isEqualTo(accordion.getPanes().get(0)));
        previousButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            TitledPane current = accordion.getExpandedPane();
            int index = accordion.getPanes().indexOf(current);
            TitledPane previous = accordion.getPanes().get(index - 1);
            current.setCollapsible(true);
            previous.setCollapsible(true);
            accordion.setExpandedPane(previous);
            previous.setCollapsible(false);
            current.setCollapsible(false);
        });

        Button nextButton = new Button("Next");
        nextButton.disableProperty().bind(accordion.expandedPaneProperty().isEqualTo(accordion.getPanes().get(accordion.getPanes().size()-1)));
        nextButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            TitledPane current = accordion.getExpandedPane();
            int index = accordion.getPanes().indexOf(current);
            TitledPane next = accordion.getPanes().get(index + 1);
            current.setCollapsible(true);
            next.setCollapsible(true);
            accordion.setExpandedPane(next);
            next.setCollapsible(false);
            current.setCollapsible(false);
        });

        HBox buttons = new HBox(5, previousButton, nextButton);
        buttons.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        buttons.setPadding(new Insets(5));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(accordion);
        root.setBottom(buttons);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

For what it's worth, I probably wouldn't try to use an `Accordion` as a wizard, and would just use a `BorderPane`, with the current "wizard page" in the center and next and previous buttons in the bottom. You can add a breadcrumb trail too if you need.

Comment: 10 of 10 points! Thanks it works. And even your suggestion at the end is correct. but it doesnt fit my app (i have 6 "main" pages where each one has one accordion with 4-5 sub-panes). I really use your "workaround", because I like all the out-of-the-box effects of the Accordion.